# Word 365 / Word Online -- Insert Table of Contents disabled, how to insert a TOC?

Tags: office365

I have headings at levels 1 and 2 in the document.

How do I get a TOC?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Word online does not have the full feature set of Word for desktop.

> Microsoft Word Online lets you make basic edits and formatting changes
>   to your document in a web browser.

Some things can only be done in Word for desktop. For an overview of the differences between desktop and online, see

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-word-3e863ce3-e82c-4211-8f97-5b33c36c55f8#__toc309629521

If you want to insert a TOC, you have to do that in Word for desktop.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: "If you want to insert a TOC, you have to do that in Word for desktop." Hmmm, someone at MS forgot that the point of web apps is "no software." Oh well. This doc will never have a TOC.

Comment: They never said that Word online will have the full feature set of Word for desktop. Your question has been answered. Please mark it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I feel like upvoting this answer is like accepting that policy forever :/ I guess I'll do the right thing, and hope Word 365 people do the same O:)

Comment: Did something chance since Jan 27 2019? I see at that link:

`Tables of contents can be inserted, modified, and deleted in Editing view. Navigate the document using the table of contents in both Editing view and Reading view.`

Yet I can't get it working. I'm using the free version.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe Features are being added to Word, PowerPoint and Excel online all the time, but the full set of online features will only work with an Office 365 subscription. The free version will typically be able to consume things like TOC, but not create them.

Comment: I'm using the enterprise version of o365 and the Table of Content option is greyed out even for me.

Comment: Yeah, I see the same thing. Maybe the text on the web page is wrong. I'll reach out to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like this is such a basic and common feature that it woudl be included in Word Online, but as others have stated it isn't for some reason.

However, they do make it rather easy to open in Word for desktop (assuming you have it installed).  Simply click the Open in Word link to the right of the main menu bar.

[image: Screenshot of Open in Word ability]

You don't have to even close the tab.  When you click the link a pop-up will appear letting you know it is being opened on your desktop and you can resume editing when you're finished. Add the table of contents in Word on your desktop, save it and close the desktop app.  Then click the link on Word Online to resume editing and your newly added table of contents is available in Word Online.

Comment: Thanks! I do not use local word for work documents, ever. For Work I use %100 office on line. What it does, it does. What it does not do, doesn't get done.

Comment: I'm going to have to chip in here. I've been using Google Docs since it came out. Since then I've been working in the cloud and needless to say I have 1000s of documents and I've never lost one or paid much for software in my life. Lately a few of my clients have figured out the cloud and I'm trying to help them use Office in the cloud. Every single document I create that's more than a page has a ToC. It baffles me that I have to  pay or get the licensed version to share these documents with my clients. Granted, Google also had issues with ToC in the beginning. Maybe it's a difficult problem.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe  Yes. I am completely baffled at how weak Office On Line is.